# How to fix my code for cs50 pset 1 mario less comfortable

Tags: c, cs50

My solution to cs50 pset 1 (mario less comfortable) doesn't print out the pyramid. Instead it just prints out one #. I have tried this multiple times but all i get is errors when trying to compile saying it doesn't identify int i or that the semi-colon should be moved to a new line. Once i changed to this code the errors finally stopped and it takes input correctly but it doesn't print the pyramid.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int height;
int spaces;
int hashes;
int row;

do
{
    printf("Height: ");
    height = get_int();
}

while (height < 0 || height > 23);

for (row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    ;
{

    for (spaces = (height - 1) - row; spaces >= 0; spaces--)
        ; 
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for (hashes = 2; row < hashes; hashes++)
        ;
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

This is the output in the terminal

$ make mario
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    mario.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o mario
$ ./mario
Height: 15
 #

Comment: Take out the semicolon between the `for` statement and the block that is *supposed to be* the body of the loop.  As it is now, the semicolon constitutes an empty statement serving as the loop body, and the intended loop body is executed only once.

Comment: I doubt Mario is very comfortable with your code formatting :) All of your problems come from the stray semicolons and inconsistent indention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Blaze alerady gave a perfect explanation of what is going on. I would like to add the following for clarity:

The syntax of the for-statement is roughly:

```
for ( ... ) <statement>
```

Where `<statement>` can be any statement, *including the empty statement*.

A semi-colon is a *statement terminator*. It indicates the end of a statement. If you write only a semi-colon, it terminates an *empty statement*. As a result, your loop body consisted out of the *empty statement*.

(As another example of the semi-colon as statement terminator: `2+2;` which turns the expression into a statement.)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the semicolons after the `for` loops. Those form the body of the `for` loop, so the loop doesn't do anything. So in other words, this here

```
for (spaces = (height - 1) - row; spaces >= 0; spaces--)
        ;
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
```

Just turns into

```
{
    printf(" ");
}
```

And likewise for the other two`for` loops. That's why the things that you want to happen in a loop only happen once each: what you thought was the body of the `for` loop actually has nothing to do with said loop, so it just gets run once.

Also, the loop condition here

```
for (hashes = 2; row < hashes; hashes++)
```

Is wrong, it should be the other way around. You probably want something similar to this:

```
for (hashes = 2; hashes < row*2; hashes++)
```

Finally, `int main` should return an int, so add `return 0;` to the end of the function.

Comment: You're wrong about the `while` - that is paired with the `do` and the semicolon is expected where it is

Comment: @ChrisTurner thank you for pointing this out, what was I thinking?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I've made the changes that were suggested and also added quotation marks inside of the brackets when calling get_int. It now draws the pyramid perfectly :)